# PHP Server SSL WebSocket receives binary garbage

Tags: php, ssl, websocket, server

I'm having deep trouble with implementing a PHP server websocket. It works completely fine without SSL.
However, when I switch client to "wss://" and add SSL context to the server socket, I get random binary garbage after client connects. I searched everything on the web but cannot figure it out.

Client code does basically nothing:

```
        var ws = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8888');
        ws.onopen = function() {
            console.log('ws open');
        }
```

Here is the minimal PHP code for SSL-less connection which works fine:

```
<?php
        $socket = stream_socket_server(
            'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
            $errno, $errstr,
            STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN
        );

        $cn = stream_socket_accept($socket, 99999, $name);
        $text = fread($cn, 1024);
        echo $text;
?>
```

With it, and client using "ws://", I receive normal WebSocket upgrade request which I can process. Everything is fine.

Now, I change client call to "wss://" and add SSL to server:

```
    $context = stream_context_create();
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '../ssl/cert.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'allow_self_signed', true);
    stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);

    $socket = stream_socket_server(
        'tcp://127.0.0.1:8888',
        $errno, $errstr,
        STREAM_SERVER_BIND | STREAM_SERVER_LISTEN,
        $context
    );
```

and this time I receive some binary encoded data which I'm unable to process:

> ▬♥☺☻☺☺♥♥{8T▬↕↑/Б{Ҭh#_W l0w2♣9x(j‹~Y{A∟MTT
> ::‼☺‼☻‼♥+/,0̨̩‼¶/5☺☺↨☺☺
> ↕►♦♦♦☺♣♣♣♠♠☺↕3+)**☺↔ JtD~[}▼$▲ɒNt◄vCyw-☻☺☺+♂
> **♥♦♥♥♥☻♥☺♥☻☻                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           ☺§

I also tried all kinds of keys and certificates for SSL. I used Apache and Nginx certs, I created them manually with OpenSSL, I created them with PHP code that I found on web, nothing helps. I reproduced this on Windows and Ubuntu systems with PHP7.4 and Apache and Nginx web servers, used localhost and external IP addresses, does not differ.

Comment: Is ` stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_pk', $pkFile);`  missing ?  Do you decode the message according to RFC6455 ?

Comment: I used varius combinations of 'local_pk', 'local_cert' etc parameters. Local PK needs to be present if the pem file does not contain key, I tried all variants, used combined and separate key, no help.

Before decoding any messages the socket must receive a HTTP request with upgrade headers in plain text, but it doesn't come, that's the problem. Without SSL all is OK. To be clear, the binary garbage I receive is not WebSocket encoded data, it doesn't match the format.

Comment: I use this on an UBUNTU server, with certificate from letsencrypt

stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $certFile);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_pk', $pkFile);
stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'verify_peer', false);
No problem so far.
The full codes  is at  
https://github.com/napengam/phpWebSocketServer

Comment: Thank you, the code looks similar to mine, i.e. there are the same functions and logic, I currently cannot examine it because it's too big. I will do it later. I hope to get a minimal working example from it.

Comment: Have you tryed to connect using ssl://127.0.0.1:8888  ?

Comment: yes I tried both 'ssl' and 'tls' but later I learned that it is for client sockets, server socket should always use 'tcp'.